# Is there a way to assign a CSS class to a column without having to assign it to each TD?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is there a way to assign a CSS class to a column, without having to assign it to each td?

I've got a large (1000+ row table) and need to assign a class to the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out.

Use the colgroup and col tags, and assign a class to them.

[Solution](https://gist.github.com/3183965/15d955666cb34d84f0951fbe8f293c2df10b68fe)

Comment: That does not apply the class to the cells, only the column. It lets you do some limited styling (such as the width and background colour (so long as the cells themselves are translucent).